# Heroku and Amazon CloudFront Cross-Origin Resources Sharing and Image URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have 1 question and 1 issue:

## Question: If using CloudFront, is the image URL supposed to have s3.amazonaws.com or randomblah.cloudfront.net?

`http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/project_images/photos/000/000/006/medium/IMG_3867.JPG?1438009375`

or with the actual cloudfront.net url...

`http://fdawfwe8200.cloudfront.net/bucketname/project_images/photos/000/000/006/medium/IMG_3867.JPG?1438009375`

Right now, I have this in my `production.rb`

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'fdawfwe8200.cloudfront.net'
```

## Issue: I'm getting `Redirect at origin 'http://fdawfwe8200.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header....` error

How do I fix this?

The only thing I see breaking on my site is, bootstrap icons are boxes.

Answer (score 0):

you can find documentation to help CloudFront with your Cors configuration like here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-cors

So just let your content server specifiy the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to what you want and configure your CDN to keep those headers.